# Multiple MSM administrators

Tags: multi-site-manager, control-panel

I've a MSM site and I want to create multiple administrator accounts.

---

**Example**

Admin1 => subdomain1.msmsite.com

Admin2 => subdomain2.msmsite.com

---

But the back-end/CP panel is located on subdomain1.msmsite.com/system

Is it possible to reach subdomain2.msmsite/system with Admin2?

*subdomain2.msmsite/system has a HTACCESS rewrite condition to subdomain1.msmsite/system*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your admin.php file you can uncomment line 42 and set the site short name which would effectively login anyone to that particular site no matter which domain they were logging in from.

```
//  $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'domain2_short_name';
```

If you make a copy of admin.php and rename it you could have to different login urls using the same domain: say admin.php and control.php

be sure to uncomment the next line and fill it in correctly.

```
//  $assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://domain2.com/admin.php';
```

In theory this should work and will only take a minute to two to try out.

Additionally you'll want to create separate member groups so that each administrator can only have access to what they need.

Comment: I already had this variables in my custom config. But it's fixed now, it was an .HTACCESS issue thanks for providing an answer!

Comment: Dennis, if this answer helped you, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer to select it as correct.